# How do I delete highlighted syntax in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, html, tags, highlighting

I have just started learning HTML in Notepad++ and I am playing around with the tags a lot. When my cursor is inside of an open or closed tag both are highlighted automatically in purple. I was wondering if I could delete them both while they are highlighted. If you're thinking this, no I do not want to remove all of the same tag. I just want to delete the ones that are automatically highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such option that I know of in Notepad++. But you can install the `HTML Tag` plugin (you can find it in the `Plugin Manager`), where there's a command called `Select tag and contents` which will do half of your job. The second half would be to press delete :)

Comment: I get so close to getting what I want done just to get palmed in the face last second. I downloaded HTML Tag and figured out how to highlight the matching opening and closing tag that I wanted. I press CTRL+T (Find matching tag) to highlight the tags. What happens is that both matching tags turn big and red like an error and a window pops up saying>>

An exception occured. Notepad++ cannot recover and must be shut down.
The exception details are as follows:
Code: 0x0EEDFADE
Type: Unlisted exception
Exception address: 0x7b839CF2

I feel there might be an error in his code. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: What is your Notepad++ version? Update to the last one (v6.5.1) and try again. Also instead of Ctrl+T try the Ctrl+Shift+T.